# Fix the radius when drawing a circle.

Tags: trigonometry, coordinate-systems

I found this function and it draws an oval rather than a circle. What do I need to do to fix the calculations to make a circle? Thanks.

[image]

```
Dim seg As Double = Math.PI * 2 / segments
For i As Integer = 0 To segments - 1
  Dim theta As Double = seg * i
  Dim lat As Double = _point.Lat + Math.Cos(theta) * radius
  Dim lng As Double = _point.Lng + Math.Sin(theta) * radius
  points.Add(New PointLatLng(lat, lng))
Next
```

Comment: Hard to tell for sure, but it almost seems like the coordinates that it is plotting with form circle, but the x-y scale is distorted, making the visual look wrong. Again, your code looks fine to me, so I'm wondering if it's something else behind the scenes.

Comment: What's behind the scenes is that the latitude-longitude "grid" is not a square Cartesian coordinate system at most places on the Earth's surface. The most noticeable difference is that the distance to travel one degree of longitude (used as x coordinate here) is (usually) shorter than the distance to travel one degree of latitude (used as y coordinate here).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You code will work if you are displaying a region near the equator.

Assume the earth is a sphere of radius $R$. If you choose the coordinate system so that

- The origin is the center of earth.
- The $x$-axis is pointing at the intersection of equator and the prime meridian (i.e. longitude = $0^\circ$)
- The $z$-axis is pointing towards north pole.

Then for a point on earth's surface with latitude $\theta$ and longitude $\phi$,
the spatial position of the point will be given by

$$(x,y,z) = R(\cos\theta\cos\phi,\cos\theta\sin\phi,\sin\theta)$$

If you work out the distance $\Delta s$ between two nearby points corresponds to latitude/longitude $(\theta,\phi)$ and $(\theta+\Delta\theta,\phi+\Delta\phi)$. You will find

$$\Delta s^2 \approx R^2 ( \Delta \theta^2 + \cos\theta^2 \Delta\phi^2 )$$

What this means is for same amount of small change in longitude and latitude, if you are not on the equator, the 'length' along the longitude direction will be shrinked by a factor $\cos\theta$. To compensate that, you need to expand along the longitude direction by a factor $\frac{1}{\cos\theta}$.

This means your code should become something like

```
 Dim lng As Double = _point.Lng + Math.Sin(theta) * radius / Math.Cos(_point.Lat*Math.PI/180)
```

(*Note*: I'm assuming your longitude is stored in degree).

For example, from the picture you have, you are displaying a region near Laporte, Colorado, US whose latitude is around $40^\circ 37'$N. The corresponding scaling 
factor is $\cos(40^\circ 37') \approx 0.7591$. That's why a hard coding aspect ratio $0.75$ works around there. The same aspect ratio will not work for
other latitudes.

Comment: Degrees, yes...

Answer (score 0):

There are two main ways. The first is to change how you display the data, which is not part of the code you showed. This is almost certainly the best way to handle this problem, but I can't help you much with that.

If you really want to keep the display the same and have your figure look like a circle, choose the appropriate "aspect ratio," a positive real number that give the ratio of the $x$ and $y$ coordinates to show a circle, square, and so on. Let's call that constant "Aspect." In the drawing you gave it looks like Aspect is around $0.75$.

Then change one line in your code to

> Dim lng As Double = _point.Lng + Math.Sin(theta) * radius * Aspect

Comment: Those points are just added to a polygon and that is drawn automatically by the program. 0.75 made the oval slightly worse.

Comment: I changed that to `Dim lat As Double = _point.Lat + Math.Cos(theta) * radius * 0.75` and that seems to have it! Thanks

Comment: @DonA: That seems to reverse the $x$ and $y$ coordinates, but if that works for you then great. There are several ways those coordinates could be "reversed" but that doesn't matter much here.

Comment: This was just the added push I needed to get this right. Not sure why that works but it does - I tried several sizes and they look great. Thanks again!

Comment: @DonA, $0.75$ works because the latitude of Laporte, CO is around $40^\circ 37'N$ and $\cos(40^\circ 37') \approx 0.7591$.

Comment: @achillehui ok, so I should be using that as a function to determine the apsect, right?

Comment: @DonA, Yes. as long as you are not near north or south pole, you can use it as a function to determine aspect. In fact, you don't need to calculate it everytime. Since $\cos\theta$ is changing very slowly on the map's length scale. You can compute the aspect ratio once, store it somewhere and reuse it when you move your view around. You only need to recompute it when you jump to distant places.

Comment: @achillehui Thanks, I will do that.